# Type Error for MultiComparision.tukeyhsd()

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

I have a data set with 13 columns, I want to perform multi comparison ANOVA on one of those columns using statsmodels.stats.multicomp.MultiComparison module. But I'm getting an type error message that I don't understand.

Same code that I wrote here works on other machines, I tried updating all the python and conda modules and tried executing the code again but ended up same result.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm  
multi_comp = sm.stats.multicomp.MultiComparison(data=df['col1'],groups=data['category'])   
result_string = multi_comp.tukeyhsd(alpha=0.05)
print(result_string)
```

I also tried other methods like pairwise_tukeyhsd(), same error persists for that method as well. Apart from this multicomp module, rest of my code works fine.

```
TypeError                                                             Traceback (most recent call last) in module<module>  
      1 multi_comp = sm.stats.multicomp.MultiComparison(data=data['col1'], groups=data['category'])  
----> 2 result_string = multi_comp.tukeyhsd()  
      3 result_string  

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\sandbox\stats\multicomp.py in tukeyhsd(self, alpha)  
   1011                                np.round(res[4][:, 0], 4),  
   1012                                np.round(res[4][:, 1], 4),  
-> 1013                                res[1]),  
   1014                           dtype=[('group1', object),    
   1015                                  ('group2', object),  

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\compat\python.py in lzip(*args, **kwargs)  
     60   
     61     def lzip(*args, **kwargs):  
---> 62         return list(zip(*args, **kwargs))  
     63     
     64     def lmap(*args, **kwargs):  

TypeError: zip argument #4 must support iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

That may happen due to few possible values of `category` in your data. If there are only 2 possible categories, MultiComp won't work.